# Why shadow on button is pixelated on some screen and how to avoid this?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have next button with `DropShadowEffect` inside:

```
<Button SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"> 
 <Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True">
       <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundBorder" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Rectangle.Effect>
         <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Direction="270" Opacity="0.5" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2"/>
        </Rectangle.Effect>
       </Rectangle>
      <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonBackground"/>
      ...
```

And on some specific screen it looks like:

[image]
(see buttom)

How to avoid this?

This happens only on some specified screen. If same resolution set on anoter screen (with other size) this is not happened.